# Issue in Converting String to DateTime Format

Tags: c#, sql, datetime, type-conversion

I am unable to convert the string values that has been extracted from the ddl to a DateTime datatype.

The Error Message

> An exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>   but was not handled in user code. Additional information: String was
>   not recognized as a valid DateTime.

I only require the date to be updated in the SQL database.

This is the an image of the DataDictionary and the Attribute I require would be the birthdate

[image: SQL Table]

These are my current codes that get and convert the date time.

```
string birth = ddlDay.SelectedItem.Value + "-" + ddlMonth.SelectedItem.Value + "-" + ddlYear.SelectedItem.Value;
DateTime birthDate = DateTime.ParseExact(birth, "dd-MMMM-yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
objCustomer.birthDate = birthDate;
```

Comment: What value of `birth` is failing for you?

Comment: We don't know what your DropDownLists display, so its impossible to help.

Comment: Also, of course, if you switched to using some form of date-picker control rather than separate drop-down lists, it would almost certainly expose the selected date as a `DateTime` to begin with, and then you could avoid messing around with strings and formatting entirely.

Comment: thanks its solved!

Answer (score 0):

```
string date = "01/08/2008";
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(date);
Console.WriteLine("Year: {0}, Month: {1}, Day: {2}", dt.Year, dt.Month, dt.Day);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of ParseExact you could use TryParse to be safe. ie:

```
var ddlDaySelectedItemValue = "29";
var ddlMonthSelectedItemValue = "Feb"; // February, 2, 02
var ddlYearSelectedItemValue = "2016";

DateTime birthDate;
string birth = ddlYearSelectedItemValue + " " + ddlMonthSelectedItemValue + " " + ddlDaySelectedItemValue;

if (DateTime.TryParse(birth, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out birthDate))
{
    objCustomer.birthDate = birthDate;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Change your code to:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(birth, "dd-MM-yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: This will only fix it if `ddlMonth.SelectedItem.Value` is a two digit month number (and not a full month name, as currently written)

Comment: Ok. I see. And is ddlDay.SelectedItem.Value a numeric value?